# Set a parent script presence status true so that child scripts load in wordpress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-dependencies

I didn't know how to write a good title for my problem.

I'm trying to integrate some scripts in js file and dequeue them to decrease browser requests. So let's say we have some child scripts which for some reasons I don't want to integrate them and they have dependencies on a parent script that I've dequeued it and integrated into another script file. Now I know I've loaded the parent script (inside the integrated script) and I want to broadcast its presence so that all depended child scripts load. How can I do that?

`wp_script_is` determines if a script has been enqueued. I want to make its output true as well for some handlers (parent scripts I mentioned).

Comment: What kind of script are we talking about? Core scripts or your custom scripts?

Comment: @Yuri suppose we have some plugins and we're integrating their scripts. I've done some but I'm afraid of dis-functioning due to dependencies. Or there might be functions which their conditions are if(wp_script_is('parent-script')) or something like that.

Comment: I don't think this is a good practise. The best you can do is minifying them. I wouldn't play with WP dependencies or script load priority